# Write into arrays and get length of elements in Apache Camel

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Being a noob in Apache camel, I have two questions.

1. I am trying to unmarshall a csv file using camel and my code is 
   Later I need to forward that values into another route and there I access them like

   ${body[0]}...${body[1]}.. etc.

How can I determine if the element exists, something like,

```
${body[0]}!=null.
```

1. I am able to tokenzine my input file using various delimiters. For example, if I try to achieve the same result as above, how can i save all the tokens into an array of some kind, so that once I get that array, i can later use it in a array somewhere.

Please Note that I cannot use Java here and I am restricted to use only spring dsl.

Answer (score 8):

Accessing the size of a list:

```
${body.size()}
```

Accessing the size of a list element of type `java.util.List`:

```
${body[0].size()}
```

Accessing the length of an array:

```
${body.length}
```

However, accessing the array length of a list element does not work properly (at least for Camel 2.13.1):

```
${body[0].length}
```

This returns the size of `body` and not the length of `body[0]`. You could use `groovy` instead:

```
<groovy>request.body[0].length</groovy>
```

For later use, store the `body` into a property:

```
<setProperty propertyName="myProperty"><simple>${body}</simple></setProperty>
<log message="${property.myProperty}" />
```

**EDIT:**
That we can't access the array length of a list element with `simple` is a bug. I opened a Jira issue: [CAMEL-7478](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7478).

**EDIT:**
[CAMEL-7478](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7478) is now fixed.

Comment: i apologize for the confusion, i meant assuming the element exists, the length of each element. For example, in my csv file if i have data1,data2,,data3 then i must be able to recognize that ${body[2]}.length == 0.

Comment: @Krishna CAMEL-7478 is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that works

.when(jsonpath("$.length()").isGreaterThan(0))